# intellisense not properly working visual studio 2008 for Visual C++ and MFC environment

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, intellisense

I am working in vc++ of Visual Studio 2008. In my project (VC++), I could access the INTELLISENSE only when i press CTRL+SPACE. it doesn't work automatically as like any other project ( i.e. C#, VB .Net).

so what should i do to work with the intellisense efficiently?

Answer (score 2):

Jim Brissom was correct but I think the confusion is that "Statement Completion" isn't an option, its a section title. So if you follow the menu

> Tools-->Options-->Text Editor-->C++

On the right at the top you see Statement Completion with check boxes for "Auto List members", "Parameter Information", etc

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the obvious answer: Have you checked

> Tools-->Options-->Text Editor-->C++

and made sure the "Statement completion" options are enabled?

Then, I am sorry to say that Intellisense *is* somewhat shaky in earlier versions of Visual Studio, they pretty much did a complete re-write in 2010 for this reason. This is particularly evident with C++, which is harder to parse than languages like, for example, C#.

Intellisense also breaks easily, forcing people to do all kinds of stuff to fix it (i.e. deleting corrupted NCB files etc.). There is a checklist available [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yash/archive/2007/09/19/intellisense-issues-in-visual-c-2005.aspx) for Visual Studio 2005 that is also still valid for 2008 which can help you fix things.

Comment: sorry, i couldn't find out the "Statement Completion" Option. and what i am asking means in C# if i type Me for MessageBox, it will show the intellisense automatically, but here i couldn't get until press the Ctrl+Space..

Comment: I know perfectly well what you are asking. The option is right where I pointed to in my answer, starting at the "Tool" menu in the main menu bar. Apart from not finding the option, did you read the MSDN blog entry and check if following those instructions had any influence on your problem?

Comment: @JimBrissom You must be running a different version of VS. The option is not there.

Answer (score 0):

Default C++ IntelliSense does not open automatically when you are typing except for after `.`, `->` and `::`.  The third party commercial extension [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/) does provide that behavior though.